# How do we know that the probability of finding an electron on some specific pattern is high and on other patters are not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, probability, orbitals

I have watched a video about the positions  of electrons inside of an atom  and on some specific patterns
probability of finding an electron is high for example  in- s,n,d  why?

Comment: Could you please explain what "positrons inside of an atom" and "s,n,d" is? (v1)

Comment: If the video is online, you could also post the link.

Comment: What is your background in physics? Do you know any level of quantum mechanics?

Comment: s,d ,p  i mean orbitals  , positions - position of electron in atom